# Opposite of beleaguered

Tags: single-word-requests

I wanted an adjective word that describes the state of being surrounded/encircled by support.

For example, the way a very important person might be surrounded by 8 lawyers or advisers.

The opposite word that comes to mind is *beleagured* which captures the 'encircling' element but carries the meaning that those who are surrounding you are foes rather than allies.

Example sentence : "I was ***** by a throng of lawyers."

Comment: What's wrong with "supported"?

Comment: I want a word that captures the sense that you're physically surrounded by support. Like "beleaguered" except with guns pointing away from you than at you lol.

Comment: Entourage?  - a group of people attending or surrounding an important person.

Comment: @piccolo Please give the sentence in which you wish this word/phrase to appear. English is heavily reliant upon context, without which the thread will dissolve into a matter of opinion.

Comment: When you  ask for "a word" there is room for confusion. Please always state whether you want a noun, an adjective, or a verb, etc.  In this case, I think you are asking for an adjective - am I right?

Comment: @Grewbeard chasly added

Comment: Doesn't your own word "surrounded" serve you well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that **flanked** was the best word that captures both the connotations of support and physical surrounding.

Comment: You need to add a supporting reference, linked and attributed, to show that the positive (buoy) sense is at least connoted. '... flanked by enemies' is quite idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

***buoyed***

> to sustain or encourage;  keep from sinking

[-Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/buoyed)

I was ***buoyed*** by a throng of lawyers.

A style suggestion: :

> I was ***buoyed*** by a *pod* of lawyers.

*pod* describes a school of dolphins. In the wild and around the world,  Dolphins  have been observed supporting weaker or sick members to keep them from drowning.

Comment: +1 because it metaphorically references a physical element, which I think is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I really like the imagery here as both words are related to water.

Answer (score 2):

I was **ensconced** by lawyers.

OED

**to ensconce (v.)**

> **3.** transitive. **To establish in a place or position for the purpose:**
>
> **b. of security, comfort, ‘snugness’, etc.** Chiefly reflexive.
>
> 1847   Ld. Lindsay Sketches Hist. Christian Art I. 121   *A vine, emblematical of the church..the four doctors of the Latin church ensconced among its branches.*
>
> 1862   E. Bulwer-Lytton Strange Story II. viii. 73   *His guest had ensconced himself in Forman's old study.*

And

> 2001 Contemporary Black Men's Fiction and Drama edited by Keith Clark *What is fundamental to the voice is that he find some deeper love to come into , while ensconced by his native black community*
>
> 2013 Music and Levels of Narration in Film: Steps Across the Border Guido Heldt *Tonio Feuersinger ( Luis Trenker ) lives in South Tyrol, ensconced by the traditional world of his mountain community,*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

> bolster verb [T] (SUPPORT)
>
> to support something, or make something stronger:
> “The UN is sending more troops to bolster the peacekeepers.”
>
> [Cambridge dictionary]([https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bolster‘](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bolster%E2%80%98)

And hence we can say the VIP was bolstered by his lawyers and bodyguards etc

The word has physical overtones as well as conceptual use as in bolstering an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

What about "ramparted" or "circumvallated ?

rampart (vb) : to surround or protect (an area) with a rampart.

circumvallate :  build ramparts or walls around ( a city or an area).

Comment: "I was ramparted by a throng of lawyers" fails the Orwell 'must not sound outlandish' test; piccolo doesn't seem to want _outlandish_ (see their own answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Phalanx**

> an organised body of persons.
>
> Example: a phalanx of lawyers

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

As for the sentence you have provided, *accompanied* sounds fine.

*He was accompanied by a throng of lawyers*.